# ListView with extended Base Adapter is not updating properly

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am currently writing a custom BaseAdapter for a ListView on Android. The List Adapter basically works fine when I first insert items in the ListView, but upon inserting new Items in the middle, the wrong items are displayed after calling

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is a simplified example (ive stripped it down to only the neccessary, if i missed to put in any information, please state a comment):

```
public class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<SingleFriend> data;
    private Activity activity = null;

    private static int needAccept = -1;
    private static int friend = -2;
    private static int waiting = -3;

    public FriendListAdapter(Activity a) {
        this.activity = a;
        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void AddFriend(SingleFriend newFriend, boolean silent) {

        int insertInto = 0;

        switch (newFriend.getFriendType()) {
            case TYPE_FRIEND_WAIT_FOR_YOUR_ACCEPT:
               insertInto = needAccept;
                break;
            case TYPE_FRIEND_WAIT_FOR_HIS_ACCEPT:
                insertInto = waiting;
                break;

            case TYPE_FRIEND_ACCEPTED:
                insertInto = friend;
                break;
        }

        if (insertInto < 0) {
            boolean found = false;
            boolean inserted = false;
            int index = 0;

            do {
                if (data.get(index).getFriendID() == insertInto) {
                    found = true;
                } else if (found) {
                    if (data.get(index).getFriendID() < 0) {
                        data.add(index, newFriend);
                        inserted = true;
                    } else {
                        if (newFriend.getFriendName().compareToIgnoreCase(data.get(index).getFriendName()) < 0) {
                            data.add(index, newFriend);
                            inserted = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!inserted && index == data.size() - 1) {
                    data.add(newFriend);
                    inserted = true;
                }
                ++index;
            } while (index < data.size() && !inserted);
        }
        if (!silent) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            SingleFriend friend = (SingleFriend)getItem(position);
            if (friend != null) {
                switch (friend.getFriendType()) {
                    case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friendlist_topic, null);
                        vi.setTag(friend);
                        ((TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.friendTopic)).setText(friend.getFriendName());
                        break;
                    case TYPE_FRIEND_ACCEPTED:
                    case TYPE_FRIEND_WAIT_FOR_HIS_ACCEPT:
                    case TYPE_FRIEND_WAIT_FOR_YOUR_ACCEPT:
                        // TODO: Community rating!
                        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friendlist_item, null);
                        vi.setTag(friend);
                        ((TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.friendName)).setText(friend.getFriendName());
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Why is the wrong data displayed, after a Friend is inserted in the FriendList? Am I missing something? Even invalidate() does not show correct stuff (i know, invalidate is a bad option, ive just done it once for testing purposes). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many problems but I think the one you're addressing is caused (or mainly caused) by this condition check:

```
if (vi == null) {...
```

`convertView` in the `getView` method is not always null and instead recycled whereas you inflate a view for the row when it satisfies the above check. I think after you scroll up and down items will no longer be correctly associated by the content.

The other problems I noticed are,

`notifyDataSetChanged` is supposed to be called everytime the list the adapter is coupled with is modified. If you want to hide some elements then you should maintain two lists. The one for adapter is purely for display.

I think you want to insert items into the list based on availability of an ID. If that is the case then a much better way than looping the list looking for an ID is to use a Map like `HashMap<id, SingleFriend>` which can be accessed randomly by `get(id)`.

You should first understand how getView works and use [View Holder pattern](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) correctly.

Comment: Thank you, i will try that out. And no, there is never data hided, what gets inserted will be shown in the list. But thank you for that information! Edit: Thank you very much, the problem you pointed to was the cause for my bug. To avoid views get inflated again after something has been inserted, should store the view for every item to return it in getView and only inflate if this reference is null or would that be bad?

Comment: Yes but I see `if (!silent)` which calls `notifyDataSetChanged`. This check is not needed and notifyDataSetChanged should be called everytime. Anyway I hope it works out for you.

Comment: The silent option is for another function that batch inserts friends into the list. It calls itself notifyDataSetChanged after inserting more than one friend. I wanted to avoid the List to get updated to often when not neccessary.